# I can't install mysql on 14.04: "Unable to set password for the MySQL root user"

Tags: 14.04, apt, mysql

I have tried the solutions presented in [Error installing mysql server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525912/error-installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) but I still can't get it to work.  The problem i think is when I install it asks me to set password, but then i get "Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to set password for the mysql "root" user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253023/unable-to-set-password-for-the-mysql-root-user)

Comment: There are a lot of options in that other question, but none worked for me, and none were accepted by original asker either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't attempted this already, use:

```
mysql_install_db
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: Thanks this worked with a few additions.
1) The first command complained about having log_slow_verbosity, so I had to remove from the my.cnf 2) Then I had to start service. 3) /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Answer (score 1):

The "Unable to set password" message is a bit misleading. Essentially, it just means *something* went wrong when trying to set the password—which can be as generic as MySQL not running.

Run `systemctl status mysql.service` to find out if MySQL started up sucessfully. If it didn't, run `sudo journalctl -xn` and/or check the contents of `/var/log/mysql/error.log` to find out more about what's preventing it from starting.

Note that `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5` will not remove config and data files. If one of them is botched, the only way to rectify this is to:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.5
sudo rm -R /etc/mysql
sudo rm -R /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

**Important: Don't do this if you have data in your MySQL installation, as this will ERASE all your MySQL data.** On a fresh install, you've got nothing to lose. Otherwise, make sure you know what you're doing.